# Javascript != checks only value

Tags: javascript

When I execute `'null' != null` it returns true. I don't get why this happens.

If I execute  `1 != '1'` it gives returns false, which is correct because it checks value.

But why does `'null' != null` return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Short story `null`  vs `int` or `string` always false, if you don't assign a value to `int` or `string` it can be `null`

so `'null'` is a `string` with value of `'null'` and `null` is a `null` so they are not equal.

Answer (score 4):

> ... `null` expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

The string `'null'` is an object, so it's not `null`, which represents the lack of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer is correct, however you can get a more detailed explanation of how the comparison is determined here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

There is no instance where one side of the condition is null in the specifications that require the other side to be converted.  However, if one side of the condition is a number, there is a specification to convert the other side to a number.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here is image you can get ideas about type checking and equality